# How can I get faster SSH clone speeds on windows?

Tags: git, github, ssh

Using PuTTY's plink/pagent my `git clone`s seemed limited to about 65Kb/s.  Following the [instructions on this page](http://blog.netflowdevelopments.com/2015/03/11/slow-git-push-pull-speeds-try-tweaking-your-ssh-settings/) pushed that up to about 92Kb/s.

Switching to OpenSSH supplied by the MingGW install with git for windows massively increased this to about 848Kb/s, however, I am able to get 1.5Mb/s if I clone using https, ie; `git clone https://github.com/user/repo`

This seems like an SSH configuration issue.  What options are there, if any, to increase a `git clone git@github.com:user/repo`?

Comment: What about doing it using [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl)?

Comment: @ryenus I'll give it a shot out of curiosity, however WSL is not feature-complete enough yet for me to use it as development environment.

Comment: @ryenus WSL pulls the repo at about 350-450Kb/s, so about half the speed of using MingGW, but 4-5x the speed of pagent.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to play with the **encryption cipher settings** (e.g., select `Blowfish` instead of `AES`). When I did some performance tuning for `ssh` between Linux machines I could almost double the throughput rate with that (compared to default settings).

There was also a surprising impact of the different (then, `OpenSSH`) **client versions** on performance, so it may help to check the `plink` revision as well.